# how to keep objects with an old date out of my array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, date, comparison

I loop through an array of objects that all have a date property. The conditional I set inside the loop to compare the object's date to today's date should take care of just a few of the objects in the array I want kept out because of an old date, however, this conditional is removing all objects in the array for some reason.

It does not work to use getTime(). getTime removes everything from the array. Like I tried here:

```
constructor (   public navCtrl: NavController,
                                public modalCtrl: ModalController,
                                public loading: LoadingController,
                                public popoverCtrl: PopoverController,
                                public getPostSrvc: getPostsService) {

        this.listOfEvents = [];

        let that = this;

function getPostsSuccess (listOfEventsObject) {

                    for (var i in listOfEventsObject) {

                        if(listOfEventsObject[i].date.getTime() < Date.now()){

                                 that.listOfEvents.push(listOfEventsObject[i]);

                              }//close if
                   }//close for loop
    }//close function
}//close constructor
```

**UPDATE**
 
My solution:

```
export class Home {

    listOfEvents: Array<any> = []; 
    parseDate: number;
    today : number;

    constructor (   //constructor stuff ){

        for (var i in listOfEventsObject) {

            that.today = Date.now();


              that.parseDate = Date.parse(listOfEventsObject[i].date);

                 if( that.parseDate > that.today){

                        that.listOfEvents.push(listOfEventsObject[i]);

                     }//close if  


                }//close for
}//close constructor  
}//close export
```

Comment: What is the value of `listOfEventsObject[i].date`?

Comment: @RobG date has the date of a selection from a date picker on a form..

Comment: In that case you're probably comparing a string like "2017-06-21" to a number like 1498078203780.

Comment: In case `listOfEventsObject[i].date` is a string, you can try this: `if (Date.parse(listOfEventsObject[i].date) < Date.now()) { ... }`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan how do I deliver you the bounty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as mentioned by RobG in a comment, the value of `listOfEventsObject[i].date` is a string, you can parse it first, and compare the resulting Date value to `Date.now()`:

```
if (Date.parse(listOfEventsObject[i].date) < Date.now()) { 
    ... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure since I don't know what kind of data `listOfEventsObject[i].date` has. 
But if that data contain timestamps, you can convert it to milliseconds and compare it to `Date.now()`.

`if (listOfEventsObject[i].date.getTime() < Date.now())`

let me know if this isn't the answer you looking for, cheers.

Comment: The `<` operator uses the [*abstract relational comparison*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-abstract-relational-comparison) algorithm that coerces dates to number, so there is no practical difference between `date < Date.now()` and `date.getTime() < Date.now()`.